# Clojure (load-file) gives an error

Tags: clojure

Whenever I try to use (load-file) on my home computer (OSX) it throws the following error:

`IllegalArgumentException Parameter declaration comp should be a vector  clojure.core/assert-valid-fdecl (core.clj:6732)`

When I load the same file on my Windows box at work it works. What is the difference between (load-file "C:\clojure\pc-3.clj") and (load-file "/Users/myname/clojure/pc-3.clj") that is throwing the error. Other than the path structure with the slashes is different but I don't understand why this is not working on my both systems.

BTW: Other than OS both systems are running JRE 1.7_025 with clojure-1.5.1.

UPDATE: 
I was asked for a stack trace and I'm not sure how to do this just started working with Clojure. But emacs nrepl-error buffer listed this out for me:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.lang.String
                                       RT.java:318 clojure.lang.RT$3.invoke
                                  NO_SOURCE_FILE:1 user/eval278
                                Compiler.java:6619 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
                                Compiler.java:6582 clojure.lang.Compiler.eval
                                     core.clj:2852 clojure.core/eval
                                      main.clj:259 clojure.main/repl[fn]
                                      main.clj:259 clojure.main/repl[fn]
                                      main.clj:277 clojure.main/repl[fn]
                                      main.clj:277 clojure.main/repl
                                  RestFn.java:1096 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                         interruptible_eval.clj:56 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate[fn]
                                      AFn.java:159 clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
                                      AFn.java:151 clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo
                                      core.clj:617 clojure.core/apply
                                     core.clj:1788 clojure.core/with-bindings*
                                   RestFn.java:425 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
                         interruptible_eval.clj:41 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/evaluate
                        interruptible_eval.clj:171 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/interruptible-eval[fn]
                                     core.clj:2330 clojure.core/comp[fn]
                        interruptible_eval.clj:138 clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible-eval/run-next[fn]
                                       AFn.java:24 clojure.lang.AFn.run
                      ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker
                       ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run
                                   Thread.java:724 java.lang.Thread.run`

UPDATE: Found out what the problem was today. I was having the exact same problem with my Windows box turns out that the original answer was correct but my assumption that it had to do with (load-file) was incorrect. The file I was loading had a function that was not using a vector [] as part of the function itself. Clojure was doing the correct thing (but I totally forgot about this) when loading the file checking the syntax to make sure that everything was complete in the file. My function wasn't so it wouldn't load the file. I forget that LISPs do this and that it's a feature not a bug (reason why I like LISPs).

I'm new to clojure but not to LISPs and I should have realized this. The file is my study file. All the examples I retype from the REPL why studying and the reload the file with the newest to make sure I typed it in correct. It appears that when I added the newest function to file I retyped it incorrect and didn't reload the file to check it. When I went away and closed down the REPL and then came back after dinner and tried to reload the file it wouldn't load.

So sorry for being a waste of time. But thanks for the help, and quickly too. The original answer was correct I just forgot to recheck all the functions in the file.

Comment: what version of Clojure (so I can look at the correct line 6732)

Comment: could you include more of the stack trace? So I can see if this is a problem running the compiler, or a problem detected by the compiler in the file.

Comment: that is all that was printed

Comment: That's exactly what I was asking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error indicates that the compiler was processing something like

```
(defn function-name comp (do-stuff ...))
```

or perhaps

```
(defn [arg1] comp (do-stuff ...))
```

instead of

```
(defn function-name [comp] (do-stuff ...))
```

`load-file` takes a string not a vector `(load-file "path/to/file.clj)` 
Could it be that the code is not the same on the two systems?
Could there be a difference in path interpretation `/` vs `\` causing something else to get loaded?

Comment: I do know that I checked out the doc and it said to use load-file as such: `(load-file [name])` but that gives me the error `ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.lang.String  clojure.lang.RT$3.invoke (RT.java:318)`

Comment: Actually, this error will only turn up in code like `(defn foo (comp ...))` or `(defn [] (comp ...))`, and not in any of the cases you guessed.

Comment: both of those are invalid expressions. should be (defn foo [arg1] ((comp function1 function2) arg1))

Comment: I believe that I'm now insane. Just got back to work this morning and I'm unable to load the file on my windows box. Receiving the same exact error. I don't know what I did yesterday to be able to create and load the file with (load-file) but I'm received the exact same error. Per documentation all \ have to be converted to / on the windows box. So I have no idea why this isn't working.